# Is it okay to have a combination of both Shared Servers and Dedicated Servers in an Oracle DB?

Tags: database, oracle, dedicated-server

currently I'm seeing both shared and dedicated servers running in test instances but only dedicated servers running in production instances. the test instances are running much much slower and I was wondering if that's what this was.

thanks for the help.

Comment: It is hard to say without more information. My guess is that the use of shared servers is not causing your test instances to be slower than production. But it depends on a lot of factors. We use shared servers on a high volume production system and get good performance.

Comment: are you running both shared and dedicated together on one of the test instances or is it just one or the other on the instances?

Comment: We are running both on our test and production databases. In production the web servers connect using shared server connections but batch jobs and ggs replication use dedicated connections.